# Is this result based on factorials true?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, factorial

While solving some questions based on factorials, I noticed a pattern and sat down to prove what I had been observing, for all $n$.

I solved some questions like this one:

Solve for $x$ - $$\frac{1}{6!} + \frac{1}{7!} = \frac{x}{8!}$$

On computing, I found out that the value of $x$ came out to be $8^2 = 64$.

On solving some other similar questions, I noticed that the value of $x$ came out to be the square of the denominator of $x$ itself. In other words, I can express it as follows -

Solve for $x$ - $$\frac{1}{n!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \frac{x}{(n+2)!}$$

So, the value of $x$ in such situations came out to $(n+2)^2$. Here is how I proved it -

$(n+1)! = (n+1).n!$  
 $(n+2)! = (n+2).(n+1).n!$

So, LHS becomes,
$\frac{n+2}{(n+1).n!} = \frac{x}{(n+2).(n+1).n!}$

$\implies x = (n+2)^2$

Is my intuition correct? The pattern which I noticed led me to this result. Is this result valid?

Comment: Yeah, it looks good.

Comment: You're right. :)

Comment: Nice spot, looks like simply beautiful art to me

Comment: yes you are right, the result is $64$

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you who have appreciated my efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

Technically, I wouldn't call that intuition, I'd call it a proof.

Essentially, you are seeing $m(m-1) + m=m^2$, where $m=n+2$.